# Recover incomplete download in Android Open Source Project

Tags: android, git, github, synchronization, android-source

I am trying to sync the following repo

> repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b gingerbread

and then

> repo sync

my problem is that repo sync stuck at fetching projects 99 percent. After a lot of searching, I found It want to download prebuilt package(~1.3G); however my internet connection interrupt repeatedly.

Bad news is that download resume for this package is not supported. Good news is that I found git save all temporary file in a Packfile internally. In addition, temporary files save in projects/prebuilt.git/objects/pack/ .

is there anybody to know how I can recover incomplete download?